# Blocking a click event from another click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $(li).click(doThis);

    $(a.clickMe).live('click', doThat);
});
```

And I want to block doThis when a.clickMe is clicked.  a.clickMe is located inside of the li... I want to check and see where the origin of the click came from, so I can see if a.clickMe was clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: riiiiiiigggghhhhttttttt........

Comment: Why are you using `.live()`? (I'm sure it's the wrong thing here, but I'm wondering if you're hoping it'll help with some other, unstated requirement.)

Comment: Had to use live() because other parts of page loading with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I want to check and see where the origin of the click came from"*

OK, so perhaps something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("li").click(function(e) {
       if ($(e.target).is("a.clickMe"))
          return doThat.call(this, e);
       else
          return doThis.call(this, e);
    });
});
```

That is, within a click handler for the li element(s) test whether the [`event.target` element](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is one of the `"a.clickMe"` elements and if so call `doThat()` (setting `this` and passing the `event` object). Otherwise call `doThis()`.

Comment: perfect!  I actually used if (!$(e.target).is("a.clickMe"))...and I can still use live() which I needed b/c ajax usage

Comment: Note that `$("a.clickMe").live('click',doThat)` can be replaced with `$(document).on('click','a.clickMe',doThat)` - it will have the same effect, but be a bit more efficient (because it avoids the pointless selection of all `a.clickMe` elements at bind time). Even better though is to use the same format of `.on` but replace `document` with another element that is a closer parent of the `a.clickMe` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the click event from propagating up to the `li`:

```
$(a.clickMe).live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Now, the event won't bubble up to the `li` and won't trigger its event handler.
});
```

Comment: Probably wanna nudge him towards `.on()` over `.live()`.

Comment: You can't stop the event propagating from within a `.live()` handler, because it has already propagated.

Comment: unfortunately @j08691 it doesn't work w/out live but good idea